# Get original dimensions of resized html image element

Tags: javascript, image, html

Is there a simple and efficient way to get the true dimensions (in JavaScript) of an image that is displayed in an `<img>` element with a potentially different rendered size (e.g. via `max-height` or `max-width`)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is present `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` DOM attributes.

For example:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "test.jpg";
image.onload = function() {
    alert('width - ' + image.naturalWidth);
    alert('height - ' + image.naturalHeight);
}
```

Or see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/pDMfx/) on jsFiddle.

More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement)

Comment: Splendiferous! That's just what I wanted. :)