# javascript image width before file upload

Tags: javascript

```
var f = this.files[0];    
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var file, img;

if((file = f)){
    img = new Image();

    img.onload = function(){
        var imgW = this.width;
        //alert(imgW); WORKING
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
}

if(imgW <100){alert('image is too small');}//NOT WORKING
```

I'm trying to get image width before file upload.

My problem is when I put var outside of `img.onload = function` I get undefine `imgW`

What I need is store this variable, anyone know where is problem?

I have try

```
var imgW;

if(file = f){
...
   imgW = this.width;
}

alert(imgW);
```

But its not working too

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the width of the image using JavaScript alone without loading the image.

It appears that you're looking for is the image's natural height and width.

[Get original dimensions of resized html image element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725024/get-original-dimensions-of-resized-html-image-element)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 provides a File API including a FileReader interface which allows reading of local files before uploading. See [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) for example.